# using in_array/php card dealer program

Tags: php

This has me stumped.  Basically I am trying to deal cards.  I get the right number of cards but it duplicates the card it randomly generates. Instead I need to have 52 different cards if the user inputs 52.

Ive been up and down trying to do this but cant figure it out.  I tried using the in_array function but to no avail

Can someone help please

```
<?php
$input = $_POST["txtNumberOfCards"];

$suit = array("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades");
$card = array("Ace","2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King");

$randsuit = rand(0,3);
$randcard = rand(0,12);

for($x = 0; $x < $input; $x++){
echo ('<img src="Images/'.$card[$randcard].'of'.$suit[$randsuit].'.gif">');
}

?>
```

Comment: this is because you are not checking to see if the card has been generated already or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to keep track of what cards have already been used and act accordingly. Also in your code you had the rand functions outside the for loop, which means that it would have only generated a random number once

```
$input = $_POST["txtNumberOfCards"];;

$suit = array("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades");
$card = array("Ace","2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King");

$setCards = array();
for($x = 0; $x < $input; $x++){
    $randsuit = rand(0,3);
    $randcard = rand(0,12); 
    if( isset($setCards[$suit[$randsuit].$card[$randcard]]) ) {
        $x--;
        continue;
    }
    echo ('<img src="Images/'.$card[$randcard].'of'.$suit[$randsuit].'.gif">');
    $setCards[$suit[$randsuit].$card[$randcard]] = true;
}
```

**[phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/bvn-erd)**: note fiddle echos out the html so it can be viewed instead of rendered.

Comment: I do like how you combined the generation checking and displaying of the cards in one for loop, however I always use a while loop with negative logic to check, so that I don't have to "undo" the counter if there is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the `$input` to an int variable using the function `intval()`

Also, randomly assign the varilabel each time of the loop to generate distinct cards:

```
<?php
$input = intval($_POST["txtNumberOfCards"]);

$suit = array("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades");
$card = array("Ace","2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King");


for($x = 0; $x < $input; $x++){
$randsuit = rand(0,3);
$randcard = rand(0,12);
echo ('<img src="Images/'.$card[$randcard].'of'.$suit[$randsuit].'.gif">');
}

?>
```

Comment: I didnt down vote, but this does not do any detection for duplicates.

Comment: @neeagl - the question was why does his code return duplicates.

Comment: @RichardChristensen it was primarily because he wasn't updating the `$randsuit` and `$randcard` values. They would always be the same value for each iteration. However, Patrick correctly pointed out, I didn't check for duplicates which I agree to.

Comment: Also you do not "need" intval(though it is good for sanitation), as php uses type coercion, so a string will be coerced to be a number when used in a place where a number is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting duplicate cards is because you are not checking to see if the card combination has been dealt already.

best solution would be to build up an array of cards and use it for checking if a card combination has been created. then echo the built array.

```
<?php
//The user input
$input = $_POST["txtNumberOfCards"];

$suit = array( "Hearts" , "Diamonds" , "Clubs" , "Spades" );
$card = array( "Ace" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King");
//$dealArray holds the cards as they are dealt and used to compare what cards have all ready been dealt
$dealArray= array( );
//$count the while loop counter variable
$count = 0;
//while the $count variable is less then the $input
while( $count < $input )
{
  //generate a card combination array
  $cardCombo = array( 'suit' => $suit[ rand( 0 , 3 ) ],//Generate Random suit
                      'card' => $card[ rand( 0 , 12 ) ] );//Generate Random card

  //if the $cardCombo array that was generated is not in the $dealArray
  if ( !in_array( $cardCombo , $dealArray ) )
  {
    //Add the $cardCombo array to the end of the $dealArray
    array_push( $dealArray , $cardCombo );
    //Output an HTML image for the $cardCombo array
    echo ( '<img src="Images/' . $cardCombo['card'] . 'of' . $cardCombo['suit'] . '.gif">' );
    $count++;//Add 1 to the counter
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch only problem is when i use my user input it doesnt return the correct number of cards...i entered 5 and i got 3 cards.

Comment: I changed it to a while loop so that it will only count up if there is not a match rather than a for loop which counts regardless of the outcome of the function.

Comment: Thanks do you mind commenting the code for me so because some of this still doesnt make sense to me.  The card combo for instance no clue what that means and thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the code a bit to implement @Patrick Evans use of echoing the card as it was created rather than having to loop through the array after it was built.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I truly appreciate it.  It does make more sense to me then the foreach